# Trying to export entire image collection but batch is not working?

Tags: google-earth-engine, batch

I am trying to download time series ET. But the batch tool is not working.
Error:

```
In users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch
Line 133: collection.size is not a function
```

```js
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');
var extent = ee.FeatureCollection("users/waqas50125012/KPK");
var StartDate = '2010-01-01';
var EndDate = '2010-12-31';
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2').select('ET').filterDate(StartDate,EndDate);
function clp(img) {
  return img.clip(extent);
}

var clip = dataset.map(clp);
var ET = clip.select('ET');
Map.centerObject(extent);
var evapotranspirationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 300.0,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'fcd163', '99b718', '66a000', '3e8601', '207401', '056201',
    '004c00', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.addLayer(ET, evapotranspirationVis, 'ET');
Map.addLayer(extent);
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive({
  image: ET.select('ET'),
  description: 'ET',
  scale: 30,
  region: extent,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
});
var plotET = ui.Chart.image.series(ET.select('ET'), extent)
            .setOptions({
                title: 'ET short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'ET'}
});

// Display.
print(plotET);
```

Comment: The error message you shared states the error is on line 133 of your code, yet you only shared thirty-something lines, please run your snippet individually and see if the error recurs, if not post the whole code.

Comment: This export method is a 3rd party script module for the Earth Engine JavaScript Code Editor. For more information on the `users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch` module, see: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch

Answer (score 1):

You're passing incorrect arguments to [`batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive`](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch#imagecollectiontodrivecollection-folder-options). The first argument needs to be the `ee.ImageCollection`; you're providing a JavaScript object literal. The function tries to call [`ee.ImageCollection.size`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-size) on something that is not an `ee.ImageCollection`. The export should be more like this:

```js
var ops = {
  scale: 30,
  region: an_extent,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
}

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(col, 'folder_name', ops)
```